# What is the fastest way to retrieve the product collection - Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-collection

I want to get the product collection to the home page for different sections.

**Method 1**

Assign the product into a category and get the category collection.

**Method 2**

Assign the product into attribute and sort the collection by attribute.

What is the fastest way to collect the data in Magento 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mujahidh, Second option is best.

- Donot need to add category to collection.There are not ***`extra join
  between category table and product tables`***.
- In 2nd option, collection will be ***run much faster when product Flat
  enable bcoz***, Collection will be come from  ***`Single Table`***.

### Recommend Block class Code:

```
<?php
namespace {vendorname}\{Modulename}\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;


class {Classname} extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Default value for products count that will be shown
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;

    /**
     * Products count
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_productsCount;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Initialize block's cache
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('empty', 6)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('1column', 5)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-left', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-right', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('3columns', 3);

        $this->addData(
            ['cache_lifetime' => 86400, 'cache_tags' => [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG]]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    { 
        return [
           'CATALOG_PRODUCT_HOMEPAGE_COLLECTION', // add Cache
           $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
           $this->_design->getDesignTheme()->getId(),
           $this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_GROUP),
           'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
           $this->getProductsCount()
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and return product collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection|Object|\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
);

        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices(
            $collection
        )->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            '{Attribute_Code}',
                '{FilterCondtionAndValue}'
        )->addAttributeToSort(
            '{Attribute_Code}',
            'desc'
        )->setPageSize(
            $this->getProductsCount()
        )->setCurPage(
            1
        );

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection with new products
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->setProductCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Set how much product should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @param int $count
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setProductsCount($count)
    {
        $this->_productsCount = $count;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get how much products should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsCount()
    {
        if (null === $this->_productsCount) {
            $this->_productsCount = self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT;
        }
        return $this->_productsCount;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::CACHE_TAG];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Amit Bera,
Here what i want is i want to retrieve some products to sliders in home page.Ex Latest products,Recommended products.
So for this shall i add a new category or add an attribute?

Comment: add an attribute and also enable this attribute to "Used in Product Listing"